# ideas for redoing flowerbed

Tags: plant-recommendations, ground-cover, outdoor, planning

I was thinking of redoing this flowerbed, since it looks kinda terrible :D

The white-ish stuff is a pretty resilient ground-cover, although not very pretty.
In spring there are a few tulips. What would your suggestions be to pretty this flowerbed up? I Would like to keep the upkeep-work low.

[image: A]

Comment: Before to start doing anything, look around you. Are there invasive species? (e.g. Reynoutria japonica (Poligono del Giappone). Personally I like much more lawn/flowered fields with some flower beds/small fruit trees: they enlarge your garden. but I recommend you to look around you and take some photo of good gardens. We can help you on identify the flowers, and to tell you how to build a similar garden.

Answer (score 2):

There is Hedera helix in your bed (ivy), which will make adding plants very difficult. The soil will be full of ivy roots which are hard to get rid of; these roots will also be preventing the soil from suffering erosion by falling off or being washed down the slope of the bed. Even if you clear an area for replanting, the ivy roots will very soon take it back over, and there's the added problem of how to prevent soil erosion in the meantime. I imagine the ivy was planted to stabilise the area because of the steep gradient - if you try removing all the ivy, intending to replant, there is a real risk of serious erosion. If you want to clear and replant, I'd recommend you seek a suitably qualified landscape architect or garden designer to carry out the works.

Comment: The retaining wall looks like it has seen better days as well. Is there a drainage channel exit at the bottom right of the picture? (Partly hidden by a stone slab).

Comment: I hadn't thought about the erosion Problem. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: There is a drainage, however it's not under the stone on the bottom right, (The stone slab is a stone bench.) The drainage is further left.

Comment: considering this I could leave the ivy as is. Any Ideas on what plants / ground-cover won't be suppressed by ivy? The only thing I can think of would be small trees, bushes or shrubs. (Which is totally fine by the way)

Comment: What's the depth of soil? Is it deep enough for larger shrubs/small trees? Though truth be told, the chances of a tree or shrub being able to spread its roots out to thrive surrounded by ivy roots are very slim, even if you clear some space - the ivy is established, the new plants won't be.

Comment: The soil should be enough for a shrub, although your'e right about the roots. I think I will check if I find a shrub to plant there, that's already of decent size, remove the ivy in a small circumference, and cover the soil with a stabilizing net. (One that will decompose after a couple of years.  - Thanks!